# Order of init scripts

Tags: sysvinit

I'm looking at all the links in my `/etc/rc6.d` to init scripts that execute on runlevel 6 (shutdown).  The K-prefixed scripts are ordered by number and then the S-prefixed scripts.  How do I know how the kill scripts will execute relative to the start scripts?  Or are only you only guaranteed order based on the subgroup?

```
K11watchdog -> ../init.d/watchdog
K95collectd -> ../init.d/collectd
S20sendsigs -> ../init.d/sendsigs
S30urandom -> ../init.d/urandom
S31umountnfs.sh -> ../init.d/umountnfs.sh
S40umountfs -> ../init.d/umountfs
S60umountroot -> ../init.d/umountroot
S90reboot -> ../init.d/reboot
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All K* scripts are always run before any S* scripts, at least in Debian 6's `/etc/init.d/rc`. (In other words, there are separate "stop" and "boot" stages.)

Note that some implementations don't actually guarantee order *within* the stage – e.g. Debian 6 may use `startpar` to run several scripts in parallel, if they don't explicitly declare dependencies on each other. (Systemd on Debian 8 always does that, even for imported sysvinit scripts.)